# how can i get image more than one video in ffmpeg in a loop

Tags: vb.net, video, ffmpeg, video-editing

i am writing a simple application for creating  thumbnails of multiple video somunteneously .but the problem is the image file namei.e one name  so it only save the last video thumbnail in the folder .

```
enter code here

For Each fi In aryFi
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = " -i " + fi.FullName + " -vframes 1 " & (SPath & "\" & FolderName & "\") & "%d.jpg"
proc.Start()
Next
```

the file names are like 1.mov,2.mov,3.mov..but how can i change the Every imagename .i am doing it in vb.net.
 any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can write hare the file name

```
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = " -i " + fi.FullName + " -vframes 1 " & (SPath & "\" & FolderName & "\") &fi.name &"%d.jpg"
```